# Storing different form post datas in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some forms in each page with a contineous of 4 pages.

If form 1 in page 1 submits it will call one  API from the controller then it will go to the page 2, the same thing will happen again in the page 2 and so on.

At last I want the page summary in form 4 submission .

If the form 1 has invalid value it will be redirect to the form1 page with prefilled submitted values and so on .

We store the records in db after form 4 submitted.

The API(fedex) returns lot of datas with hashes which needs to be kept upto the last form submitted .

Storing the form datas in session will be good ?

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about multi step form. Detailed tutorail is there in [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) railscast

```
def new
  session[:order_params] ||= {}
  @order = Order.new(session[:order_params])
  @order.current_step = session[:order_step]
end

def create
  session[:order_params].deep_merge!(params[:order]) if params[:order]
  @order = Order.new(session[:order_params])
  @order.current_step = session[:order_step]
  if @order.valid?
    if params[:back_button]
      @order.previous_step
    elsif @order.last_step?
      @order.save if @order.all_valid?
    else
      @order.next_step
    end
    session[:order_step] = @order.current_step
  end
  if @order.new_record?
    render "new"
  else
    session[:order_step] = session[:order_params] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "Order saved!"
    redirect_to @order
  end
end
```